# Azure Synapse External Table Location parameterization with changing date format

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

Is it possible to pass a parameter(folder /file path) to the location of Azure Synapse External Table?

LOCATION=/Windows/Folder/YYYY/MM/DD/File_name_YYYYMMDD.csv

I want to parameterize YYYY/MM/DD and File_name_YYYYMMDD.csv as paramter which changes everyday..
can i send value from Azure Data Factory to Azure Synapse

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is possible via dynamic SQL, but you cannot natively pass a parameter to a `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` statement.

Comment: Hi @jagadish dn Kindly let me know if you need more information. : )

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Azure SQL but I think create External Table is the same as Azure Synapse. We can use ADF to dynamically create EXTERNAL TABLE.

For exmple:

1. In ADF, we can declare several variables to get dynamic content.
   [image]
2. If you're using Copy activity, we can add dynamic content to `@{concat('DROP EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureInvoices CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureInvoices WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE, LOCATION = ',variables('ContainerStr'),variables('DateStr'),',CREDENTIAL = UploadInvoices );')}`.
   [image]
3. ADF will help us to create external table before copy activity.
   [image]

Comment: Hi @jagadish dn If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no direct parameterization option with normal external table definition in synapse. So in order to achieve your scenario, you would need to create the external table at run time via dynamic SQL.
Use a lookup activity or stored procedure activity wherein you pass the location value as a parameter and based on that parameter create the external table via dynamic SQL

Answer (score 0):

You can set a CETAS to a variable such as `DECLARE @cetas NVARCHAR(1000)`, then use `EXEC sp_executesql @cetas` to create the table.

Here is an example, you can change a few things then apply it to your situation.

[image: screenshot of Openrowset bulk variable]

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('bronze.test_cetas_002') IS NOT NULL
    DROP EXTERNAL TABLE bronze.test_cetas_002
    GO
    DECLARE @report_date VARCHAR(17)
    SELECT @report_date = REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate()-1, 111), '/', '') + '*/*/*.csv'
    DECLARE @cetas NVARCHAR(1000)
    SET @cetas = N'
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE bronze.test_cetas_002
        WITH (
            LOCATION = ''bronze/test002'',
            DATA_SOURCE = ds_az_test,
            FILE_FORMAT = csv_file_format
        )
    AS
    SELECT *
    FROM
        OPENROWSET(
            BULK (
                ''' + @report_date + '''
            ),
            DATA_SOURCE = ''ds_az_test'',
            FORMAT = ''CSV'',
            PARSER_VERSION = ''2.0'',
            HEADER_ROW = TRUE
        ) AS [result]'
     EXEC sp_executesql @cetas
     GO
```